# GO: Type assertion from list

Tags: go

I have stored a set of strings in a list. I iterate through the list to compare with the string `"[the]"`.

When I use the function `strings.EqualFold`, it presents this error:

> Cannot use e.Value (type interface {}) as type string in function argument: need type assertion

The code is as follows:

```
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        if(strings.EqualFold("[the]", e.Value)){
            count++

        }
    }
```

Comment: Just do not use a linked list? Any reason you cannot use a slice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Go's linked list implementation uses an empty `interface{}` to store the values in the list, you have to you use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) like the error indicates to access your value.

So if you store a `string` in the list, when you retrieve the value from the list you have to type assert that the value is a string.

```
for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
    if(strings.EqualFold("[the]", e.Value.(string))){
        count++
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Swap a "e.Value.(string)" from "e.Value".